# Is there any way of creating a two-dimensional version of scipy.stats.skewnorm plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to create a two-dimensional plot of the scipy.stats.skewnorm function. On the scipy site it gives a one dimensional version but i am unsure as to how i can turn it into a two dimensional version. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by your question, the plot shown is 2-dimensional, values and counts. Are you talking about a 3-d version? Or else what do you envision being on the 2nd dimension?

Comment: apologies sorry I meant in 3d, where we would give it a 2d input and produce an output. So the input would 2d instead of 1d, again apologies.

Comment: There's a demo for creating a [3d histogram here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html), and you can use the skewnorm distribution to create the underlying data

Comment: thank you so much for that, I apologize beforehand but would you be able to show me an example with code? that would really solidify the idea, again thank you for the help.

Comment: For a basic example, you can copy/paste the code directly from the link I posted, then instead of the place where it generates random numbers for `x, y`, you can use the distribution from the skewnorm docs: `x,y = skewnorm.rvs(4, size=1000),skewnorm.rvs(4, size=1000)`

Comment: Added the code in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To borrow code directly from these two sites:

[skewnorm docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html)

[hist3d demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import skewnorm

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#generate data from skewnorm dist
x,y = skewnorm.rvs(.2, size=1000),skewnorm.rvs(.2, size=1000)
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=4, range=[[0, 4], [0, 4]])

xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1] + 0.25, yedges[:-1] + 0.25)
xpos = xpos.flatten('F')
ypos = ypos.flatten('F')
zpos = np.zeros_like(xpos)

dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = hist.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')

plt.show()
```

[image: chart]

Comment: If i wanted to shift the  skewed distribution i would simply need to change 0.2 in the skewnorm.rvs call to another value such as 1.0 or whatever, correct?

Comment: I would assume so, but I'm less familiar with the skewnorm function, so I'd recommend reading the docs and experimenting. Good luck, and don't forget to accept the answer with the check mark if it helped you sufficiently